# AWS API Gateway Mapping Template JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've got a API stage that's **NOT** using "Lambda Proxy integration" which has a Lambda function passing an error.

In the mapping template I have this:

```
$input.path("$.errorMessage")
```

Which results in the output of this:

```
{
    "headers": {
        "apiVersion": "20190218.1",
        "isTesting": true
    },
    "body": {
        "statusCode": 503,
        "status": "Service Unavailable",
        "title": "One or more of our data providers are currently offline for scheduled maintenance"
     }
}
```

The header values are mapped to template headers and pull through correctly, however I need the body to transform to this:

```
{
   "statusCode": 503,
   "status": "Service Unavailable",
   "title": "One or more of our data providers are currently offline for scheduled maintenance"
}
```

Whatever I have tried, body always returns as a blank string, an empty body, or an invalid JSON.

This is the closest I've got but it returns an invalid JSON:
`$util.parseJson($input.path("$.errorMessage")).body`

Result (comes back with no quotes):

```
{statusCode=503, status=Service Unavailable, title=One or more of our data providers are currently offline for scheduled maintenance}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm after? I can't find a reverse for $util.parseJson (i.e, stringify).

Thanks!

Comment: By any chance do you remember what was solution for this? I am facing similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292136/aws-api-gateway-mapping-template-returns-empty-response-or-missing-quotes

Answer (score 1):

I think the original poster has probably moved on in the past 11 months, but in case anyone else stumbles across this question, `$input.json('$.errorMessage.body')` should work.