# AWS API Gateway Mapping Template returns empty response or missing quotes

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've deployed api gateway project that integrates lambda (**not** proxy) function that return base64 encoded response. Example response looks like (bear in mind that for simplicity I removed some amazon headers and changed response):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 949
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:20:39 GMT
X-Pagination-Offset: 0
X-Pagination-Count: 2
X-Pagination-Limit: 100

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
```

The response before and after decoding looks like:

```py
>>> import base64
>>> import json
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> s = "eyJib2R5IjogW3sidXVpZCI6ICI1M2EzZTk4My1mYjBkLTQ5MzEtYTc5NC1hYTI4NGEzZDNhYjMiLCAiY3JlYXRlZCI6ICIyMDIwLTExLTI3VDE3OjMwOjQzLjQwMTM3OFoifSwgeyJ1dWlkIjogImQyOTFiNmE0LWQ4NDctNGY5Ni05ZWVmLThlMDMyOGM2NjZhMiIsICJjcmVhdGVkIjogIjIwMjAtMTEtMjdUMTc6MzA6NDMuNDAxMjYzWiJ9XSwgImhlYWRlcnMiOiB7IkNvbnRlbnQtTGVuZ3RoIjogIjIwMyIsICJDb25uZWN0aW9uIjogImtlZXAtYWxpdmUiLCAiQWxsb3ciOiAiR0VULCBIRUFELCBPUFRJT05TIiwgIlgtUGFnaW5hdGlvbi1MaW1pdCI6ICIxMDAiLCAiWC1GcmFtZS1PcHRpb25zIjogIlNBTUVPUklHSU4iLCAiWC1QYWdpbmF0aW9uLUNvdW50IjogIjIiLCAiWC1QYWdpbmF0aW9uLU9mZnNldCI6ICIwIiwgIkNvbnRlbnQtRW5jb2RpbmciOiAiZ3ppcCIsICJWYXJ5IjogIkFjY2VwdC1FbmNvZGluZywgQ29va2llIiwgIkRhdGUiOiAiTW9uLCAxNCBEZWMgMjAyMCAxNToyMDozOSBHTVQiLCAiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIjogImFwcGxpY2F0aW9uL2pzb24ifSwgImNvZGUiOiAyMDB9"
>>> result = base64.b64decode(s)
>>> pprint(json.loads(result))
{u'body': [{u'created': u'2020-11-27T17:30:43.401378Z',
            u'uuid': u'53a3e983-fb0d-4931-a794-aa284a3d3ab3'},
           {u'created': u'2020-11-27T17:30:43.401263Z',
            u'uuid': u'd291b6a4-d847-4f96-9eef-8e0328c666a2'}],
 u'code': 200,
 u'headers': {u'Allow': u'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS',
              u'Connection': u'keep-alive',
              u'Content-Encoding': u'gzip',
              u'Content-Length': u'203',
              u'Content-Type': u'application/json',
              u'Date': u'Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:20:39 GMT',
              u'Vary': u'Accept-Encoding, Cookie',
              u'X-Frame-Options': u'SAMEORIGIN',
              u'X-Pagination-Count': u'2',
              u'X-Pagination-Limit': u'100',
              u'X-Pagination-Offset': u'0'}}
```

An api gateway response mapping template is `$input.body` for above response. I would like to return only `body` value.  When I change the mapping template to `$util.base64Decode($input.body)` a response body  for `GET` request is

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Allow": "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS",
    "Content-Encoding": "gzip",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Date": "Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:38:09 GMT",
    "Server": "nginx/1.19.0",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding, Cookie",
    "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",
    "X-Pagination-Count": "2",
    "X-Pagination-Limit": "100",
    "X-Pagination-Offset": "0",
    "Content-Length": "203",
    "Connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "uuid": "53a3e983-fb0d-4931-a794-aa284a3d3ab3",
      "created": "2020-11-27T17:30:43.401378Z"
    },
    {
      "uuid": "d291b6a4-d847-4f96-9eef-8e0328c666a2",
      "created": "2020-11-27T17:30:43.401263Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am interested in returning value (in this case array) from `body` key.
Mapping template like `$util.base64Decode($input.body).path('$.body')` make it returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 277
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:42:17 GMT
X-Pagination-Offset: 0
X-Pagination-Count: 2
X-Pagination-Limit: 100


[{uuid=53a3e983-fb0d-4931-a794-aa284a3d3ab3, created=2020-11-27T17:30:43.401378Z}, {uuid=d291b6a4-d847-4f96-9eef-8e0328c666a2, created=2020-11-27T17:30:43.401263Z}]
```

It is missing double quotes and this is not treated as valid json. There was a similar issue but it does not seem to solve my problem [AWS API Gateway Mapping Template JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741560/aws-api-gateway-mapping-template-json).

Mapping template like

- `$util.base64Decode($input.body).json('body')`
- `$util.parseJson($util.base64Decode($input.body).path('$.body'))`
- `$util.toJson($util.base64Decode($input.body).path('$.body'))`

return literally empty response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2020 15:44:28 GMT
x-amzn-RequestId: df62422c-fb35-4616-9f6b-0d646c2aa1e2
X-Pagination-Offset: 0
X-Pagination-Count: 2
X-Pagination-Limit: 100
```

How should response mapping template look like to return properly formatted response?